# Merging data from two tables into a third using Oracle MERGE INTO

Tags: oracle, merge, duplicates

I'm a PHP developer coming from a MySQL background, working with Oracle for the first time.  I'm trying to insert data from two tables into a third, with the functional goal of tracking user permissions to access certain products on my platform, while avoiding UNIQUE CONSTRAINT errors (i.e. adding duplicate records).  I have three tables:

```
USERS
PERMISSIONS
USER_PERMISSIONS
```

And what I want to do is add a row containing the ID from USERS, the ID from PERMISSIONS, and the ID of the current user (so we know who added the record).  Here's my attempt:

```
MERGE INTO USER_PERMISSIONS up 
    USING (
        SELECT 
            USERS.ID, 
            PERMISSIONS.ID 
        FROM 
            USERS, 
            PERMISSIONS 
        WHERE 
            PERMISSIONS.NAME = 'productalpha'
        AND 
            USERS.SHORTNAME = 'username'
    ) ON (
        USERS.ID = up.USER_ID 
        AND 
        PERMISSIONS.ID = up.PERMISSION_ID
    ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        USER_ID, 
        PERMISSION_ID, 
        LAST_UPDATED_BY_USER_ID
    ) VALUES (
        USERS.ID, 
        PERMISSIONS.ID, 
        '1'  
    );
```

However I'm running into trouble with INVALID IDENTIFIER errors.  I'm aware that the USING (SELECT) portion of the query tells the query what tables I will be using, but I'm not sure how to correctly identify them so that the query works.  Is this the wrong approach?  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks much!

EDIT: The exact error message I receive is:

```
Error at Command Line : 16 Column : 9  
Error report -  
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PERMISSIONS"."ID": invalid identifier  
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: **Please** post the complete error message details, and line it is occurring on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your ON clause. The joining criteria must reference the USING clause but you are referencing the underlying table names instead. The solution is quite simple: alias the USING clause and label the ON clause with the alias. Like this::

```
MERGE INTO USER_PERMISSIONS up 
    USING (
        SELECT 
            USERS.ID as user_id, 
            PERMISSIONS.ID as permission_id
        FROM 
            USERS, 
            PERMISSIONS 
        WHERE 
            PERMISSIONS.NAME = 'productalpha'
        AND 
            USERS.SHORTNAME = 'username'
    ) q ON (
        q.user_id = up.USER_ID 
        AND 
        q.permission_id = up.PERMISSION_ID
    ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        USER_ID, 
        PERMISSION_ID, 
        LAST_UPDATED_BY_USER_ID
    ) VALUES (
        q.user_id, 
        q.permission_id, 
        '1'  
    );
```

Note that you also need to alias the two ID columns inside the USING clause, to avoid the ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined error.

Comment: Thanks, very clear!  Would you mind updating your answer to reflect aliased column names, for the benefit of others who view this in the future?  Will accept once that's done!

Comment: Ach, my mistake - I was looking at the FROM clause instead of the SELECT clause.  Accepted, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The query in the `USING` clause is an in-line view, so the aliases `USERS` and `PERMISSIONS` are not valid outside it.  Try this:

```
MERGE INTO USER_PERMISSIONS up 
    USING (
        SELECT 
            USERS.ID, 
            PERMISSIONS.ID 
        FROM 
            USERS, 
            PERMISSIONS 
        WHERE 
            PERMISSIONS.NAME = 'productalpha'
        AND 
            USERS.SHORTNAME = 'username'
    ) source ON (
        source.ID = up.USER_ID 
        AND 
        source.ID = up.PERMISSION_ID
    ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        USER_ID, 
        PERMISSION_ID, 
        LAST_UPDATED_BY_USER_ID
    ) VALUES (
        source.ID, 
        source.ID, 
        '1'  
    );
```

Comment: Great answer.  If APC hadn't beat you to it, this would be the accepted answer :D  Thank you for the feedback!